# Dereferencing object pointer to stack stored object (destructor call)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, destructor

Am I leaking memory in the code snippet shown below?

```
MySet.cpp

MySet *MySet::unionMS(MySet& newSet)
{
    MySet *resultSet = new MySet(*this);
    [...] 
    // logic goes here
    [...]
    return resultSet;
}
```

And in

```
int main(){
     [...]
     MySet set3;
     set3 = *set1.unionMS(set2);
 }
```

So when `resultSet` leaves the scope pointer variable is destroyed. However, when happens to the underlying object? Is it being copied to the caller and then destroyed?

Comment: This is simple: `/* answer goes here */`. You're welcome!

Comment: What's `resultSet`?

Comment: Apologies for being obscure. First I accidentally deleted original paste from the method and then copy pasted a fragment of a different method. Current version is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, you're leaking memory. Your code contains `new`, and code that contains `new` leaks memory in general (except when it has been written extremely carefully by experts, which is almost never the case in the wild).

Comment: The title is misleading. You don't have pointers to stack allocated objects in the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So when `resultSet` leaves the scope pointer variable is destroyed.

Correct. The function returns a copy of the mentioned pointer.

> However, when happens to the underlying object?

Nothing. It was allocated dynamically. Dynamically allocated objects exist until they are deleted.

> Is it being copied to the caller...

The returned pointer is dereferenced in the statement

```
set3 = *set1.unionMS(set2);
```

Then, the object is copied to `set3`. So yes, the object is copied.

> ... and then destroyed?

No, since you never called `delete`, the object wasn't destroyed. After dereferencing the returned, *temporary* pointer, you don't store it anywhere. Because the value of the pointer is then lost, the object can no longer be destroyed. You have leaked the memory.

There seems to be no advantage to use dynamic allocation in this example. I recommend returning a copy of an automatic object instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I understand correctly I would either have to do the following in main: `MySet *set3;`  `set3 = set1.differenceMS(set2);` and then explicitly delete set3 before main leaves the scope. The problem with returning by value is that MySet holds a dynamically alocated `int* mySet` which is int[] array. In this particular case I believe I have to pass pointer, because otherwise the values in the int*MySet won't be passed?

Comment: The data pointed by members of `MySet` would be copied, if you have correctly implemented the copy and move constructor of `MySet`. But yeah, if you are to use dynamic allocation, then what you propose would be the correct way to delete `set3`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have a `new` and no matching `delete`. The simplest fix is to change `unionMS` to return a `MySet` instead of a `MySet*`.

```
MySet MySet::unionMS(MySet& newSet)
{
    MySet resultSet(*this);
    [...] 
    // logic goes here
    [...]
    return resultSet;
}

int main(){
     [...]
     MySet set3 = set1.unionMS(set2);
 }
```